# Why my room doesnt work properly in kotlin compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been working on dictionary app for a while in kotlin with compose. I want the user to be able to create their own dictionary as a feature of the application.I use the room database for this, I have done all the integrations, but I don't understand why it keeps getting errors. I checked everything but couldn't find where the problem is originating from. I will share my codes and errors.

**errors**

```
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - kotlin.Unit
C:\Users\enest\AndroidStudioProjects\DictionaryApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\enestigli\dictionaryapp\data\locale\OwnDicDao.java:11: error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (kotlin.Unit).
    public abstract java.lang.Object GetAllDictionary(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^
C:\Users\enest\AndroidStudioProjects\DictionaryApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\enestigli\dictionaryapp\data\locale\OwnDicDao.java:11: warning: The query returns some columns [dicName, creationTime, uid] which are not used by kotlin.Unit. You can use @ColumnInfo annotation on the fields to specify the mapping. You can annotate the method with @RewriteQueriesToDropUnusedColumns to direct Room to rewrite your query to avoid fetching unused columns.  You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: dicName, creationTime, uid. Fields in kotlin.Unit: .
    public abstract java.lang.Object GetAllDictionary(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                     ^
C:\Users\enest\AndroidStudioProjects\DictionaryApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\enestigli\dictionaryapp\data\locale\OwnDicDao.java:33: error: Unused parameter: dicId
    public abstract java.lang.Object Update(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
                                     ^
C:\Users\enest\AndroidStudioProjects\DictionaryApp\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\enestigli\dictionaryapp\data\locale\OwnDictionaryDatabase.java:7: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
public abstract class OwnDictionaryDatabase extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:243)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
```

**OwnDicDao**

```
@Dao
interface OwnDicDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM OwnDictionaries")
    suspend fun GetAllDictionary()

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun Insert(dictionary: OwnDicEntity)

    @Delete
    suspend fun Delete(dictionary: OwnDicEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM owndictionaries")
    suspend fun DeleteAll()

    @Query("UPDATE OwnDictionaries SET dicName =:dicName")
    suspend fun Update(dicId:Int?,dicName:String)



}
```

When I comment out the `@Query` anatations, that is, when I comment out the `Update` and `GetAllDictionary` functions, the problems disappear and the application works properly. I noticed this.

**for example like this**

```
/*  @Query("UPDATE OwnDictionaries SET dicName =:dicName")
    suspend fun Update(dicId:Int?,dicName:String)*/

 /* @Query("SELECT * FROM OwnDictionaries")
    suspend fun GetAllDictionary()*/
```

**OwnDicEntity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "OwnDictionaries")
data class OwnDicEntity(

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dicName") val ownDicName:String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "creationTime") val creationTime:String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int? = null
)
```

**OwnDicDatabase**

```
@Database(
    entities = [OwnDicEntity::class],
    version = 1
)

abstract class OwnDicDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val ownDicDao: OwnDicDao
}
```

**build.gradle(Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id  'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.enestigli.dictionaryapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"



    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0"

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38.1"
    //implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03'

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.1'

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0"


    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)


    // Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.3.0"


    //Material theme3
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha12"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.0-alpha12"

    //skrape{it}
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'

    //compose
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"


}
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.1'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I delete room completely, for example, when I delete classes such as dao, database, entity, it works as before, and as I said above, it works when I remove or comment @Query queries. What could be the problem, I've been dealing with these errors for 2 days. I have not encountered such errors when using room in my previous projects.

Comment: You are missing some configuration. Head to the docs and read through the `get-started` guide

Comment: what I am missing ? can you share docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue from as your quires returning some data so you need implement return type to suspend function like below

```
    @Dao
interface OwnDicDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM OwnDictionaries")
    suspend fun GetAllDictionary():List<OwnDicEntity> // here change

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun Insert(dictionary: OwnDicEntity)

    @Delete
    suspend fun Delete(dictionary: OwnDicEntity)

    @Query("DELETE FROM owndictionaries")
    suspend fun DeleteAll() // here no change need because it returns nothing

    @Query("UPDATE OwnDictionaries SET dicName =:dicName")
    suspend fun Update(dicId:Int?,dicName:String):List<OwnDicEntity> //here change



}
```